# overlapping feature values values in matlab

Tags: matlab

If I have a matrix

```
F=[ 24 3  17 1;
    28 31 19 1;
    24 13 25 2;
    47 43 39 1;
    56 41 39 2];
```

in the first three columns I have feature values a forth column is for class labels. my problem is to get rid of same feature values when class label is different for that particular values.

like for `F` matrix I have to remove the rows 1,3,4 and 5 ,because for first column there are 2 different values in column four and same is for third column (39 and 39)as class label again got changed.
so output should look like

```
F=[28 31 19 1];
```

Comment: i have tried matlab's ismember function but got problems when checking for second class

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward approach would be iterating over the columns, counting the number of different classes for each value, and removing the rows for values associated to more than one class.

#### Example

```
F = [24 3 17 1; 28 31 19 1; 24 13 25 2; 47 43 39 1; 56 41 39 2];

%// Iterate over columns
for col = 1:size(F, 2) - 1

   %// Count number of different classes for each value
   [vals, k, idx] = unique(F(:, col));
   count = arrayfun(@(x)length(unique(F(F(:, col) == x, end))), vals);

   %// Remove values associated to more than one class
   F(count(idx) > 1, :) = [];
end
```

This results in:

```
F =
    28    31    19     1
```

Comment: the efficiency of each feature is defined as the fraction of all remaining points separable by that feature.how can i do this.kindly help me about that???waiting for a prompt reply

Comment: @saminaraz I'm not sure what you mean. Are you changing your current question or asking a new one? Did my answer resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Another take at the problem, without `arrayfun` (edited)

```
F = [24 3 17 1; 28 31 19 1; 24 13 25 2; 47 43 39 1; 56 41 39 2];
```

Separate both classes:

```
A1 = F(F(:,4)==1,1:3);
A2 = F(F(:,4)==2,1:3);
```

Replicate them to a 3D matrix to compare each line of class1 with each line of class2:

```
B2 = repmat(shiftdim(A2',-1),size(A1,1),1);
B1 = repmat(A1,[1,1,size(A2,1)]);
D4 = squeeze(sum(B1 == B2,2));
```

remove rows duplicated rows

```
A1(logical(sum(D4,2)),:) = [];
A2(logical(sum(D4,1)),:) = [];
```

reconstruct original matrix

```
R = [A1 ones(size(A1,1),1);A2 2*ones(size(A2,1),1)];
```

Comment: samina naz commented in his/her [new (duplicated) question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431103/overlapping-feature-values-and-efficient-features-calculation) - quoting: "no the answer was gud..i appreciate.but i read at some place that arrayfun is a bit slow .so thats why i wanted to try using some othr logic." I answered here and now I'm waiting to see if that was really a concern. No reply for a day and now I feel a bit stupid.

Comment: I just ran your code and it has a bug. You remove any two rows with a duplicate element, but what you need to do is remove these rows _only_ if the elements are associated with a different class (at least that's what it says in the question).

Comment: @DedekMraz i just ur post...u r right that i havent mentioned that perfromance is an issue.. i just wrote that i have read at some place while googling about arrayfun. so cheers