# overlapping feature values and efficient features calculation

Tags: matlab

If I have a matrix

```
F=[ 24 3  17 1;
    28 31 19 1;
    24 13 25 2;
    47 43 39 1;
    56 41 39 2];
```

in the first three columns I have feature values a forth column is for class labels. my problem is to get rid of same feature values when class label is different for that particular values.

like for F matrix I have to remove the rows 1,3,4 and 5 ,because for first column there are 2 different values in column four and same is for third column (39 and 39)as class label again got changed. so output should look like

```
 F=[28 31 19 1];
```

and other problem is in efficiency of each feature calculationTthe efficiency of each feature is defined as the fraction of all remaining points separable by that feature.how can i do this.kindly help me about that???waiting for a prompt reply

Comment: yeah.but is associated with it.

Comment: And you don't like EitanT's answer to your previous question?

Comment: no the answer was gud..i appreciate.but i read at some place that arrayfun is a bit slow .so thats why i wanted to try using some othr logic